# Lorentz Invariance in Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am reading through Volume I of Steven Weinberg's books on QFT and on page 243 he states that 'Lorentz invariance is guaranteed in perturbation theory as long as we add appropriate local but non-covariant terms in the Hamiltonian density'.

Is there some article in the physics literature where this statement is proved in rigorous (or semi-rigorous) terms?  I don't have any reason to doubt it, I was just wondering if a proof had been supplied.

Comment: In pages 277 - 279 Weinberg deals with an example of this. This should convince you that there are indeed situations in which one needs to add these local but non-covariant terms and give you an idea of how that goes. If your question, however, is whether there is a proof that it is always possible to do so then Weinberg says in page 243 itself that "though a rigorous proof is lacking, there is no reason to doubt that this is always possible". I'm unaware if some proof has been furnished since he wrote that.

Comment: Also, quoting Weinberg (page 279): *It may seem that this is a rather ad hoc procedure. Fortunatelly, in the canonical formalism discussed in the following chapter, the non-covariant term in the Hamiltonian density needed to cancel non-covariant terms in the propagator arises automatically. This, in fact, forms part of the motivation for introducing the canonical formalism*.